# Oracle Table alias in join

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

is it possible to use the table alias in an ON-Statement?

SQL Statement:

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT("row", XMLATTRIBUTES(rownum as "order"),
    (
       SELECT
          XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("attribute",XMLATTRIBUTES(z as "identifier") ) )
       FROM b
       LEFT JOIN c
          ON c.ID = b.cID 
          AND c.example = table_alias.example
    )
)
FROM
(
    SELECT example FROM x ORDER BY y
) table_alias
```

I'm getting the error that `table_alias.example` is an invalid identifier.
If I move the `c.example = table_alias.example` into a WHERE Statement it works, but of course I'll get the wrong result.

Anyone have an idea?

TY
frgtv10

Comment: I think you have one right parenthesis more than needed.

Comment: that must be a copy past fault.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("attribute",XMLATTRIBUTES(z as "identifier") ) )` instead?

Comment: Sorry, thats my fault. Does not have any effect on the error...

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
   SELECT XMLELEMENT("row", XMLATTRIBUTES(rownum as "order"),
         ( SELECT XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("attribute"),XMLATTRIBUTES(z as "identifier") ) ) 
            FROM b, c, x
            where c.ID = b.cID(+) AND c.example = x.example
         )
    ) from dual
```